# add again button in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have this code

add_view_child.php

```
<?php echo form_open('EmpFamilyInfo/add_childinfo'); ?>
        <div class="box-body">
          <div class = 'col-md-6 col-sm-offset-6'>
            <button class="btn btn-info fa fa-save" type="submit">&nbsp Save</button>
            <a href = '<?php echo base_url().'EmpFamilyInfo/other_childinfo/'.$this->uri->segment(3); ?>' class = 'btn btn-primary fa fa-save'>&nbsp Add Another</a>
            <a href = '<?php echo base_url().'EmpFamilyInfo/parentsinfo_father/'.$this->uri->segment(3); ?>' class = 'btn btn-danger fa fa-arrow-circle-right'>&nbsp Skip</a>
          </div>
        </div>
         <?php

          echo form_close();
        ?>
```

as you can see i have a form submit where i submit it to

```
public function add_childinfo(){

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('NAME',   'Name of Child' ,'trim|required|max_length[100]');

    if($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE){

        $this->child_info();
    }else{

        if($query = $this->EmpFamilyInfo_Model->insert_childinfo()){

            redirect('EmpFamilyInfo/parentsinfo_father/'.$this->uri->segment(3));

        }else{

            $this->child_info();
        }
    }   
}

public function parentsinfo_father(){

    $data['content_view'] = 'EmpFamilyInfo/add_view_father';
    $this->templates->admin_template($data);

}
```

now, as you can also see, i have this href to the function other  child info. which, what i wanted it to do is to save the data then redirect it back to my form so i can input information again.

heres the code

```
public function other_childinfo(){

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('NAME',   'Name of Child' ,'trim|required|max_length[100]');

    if($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE){

        $this->child_info();
    }else{

        if($query = $this->EmpFamilyInfo_Model->insert_childinfo()){

            redirect('EmpFamilyInfo/child_info/'.$this->uri->segment(3));

        }else{

            $this->child_info();
        }
    }   
}

public function child_info(){

    $data['content_view'] = 'EmpFamilyInfo/add_view_child';
    $this->templates->admin_template($data);

}
```

the problem is when i click the add another button, it does redirect to function other_childinfo but it does not do anything. how can i do this correctly?

Comment: are u including helper ?? $this->load->helper('url');

Comment: yes.  thats not the problem. the problem is that how can i have two submit buttons in one. form

Comment: try var_dump the query under other_childinfo() function then look if you get a result

Comment: Try replacing the output under your if and else statement also. for example if the form validation run == false then echo "false" to see what's going wrong.